# Given a graph G (V,E), are there any algorithms which returns a set of edges to be removed, such that their sum is maximum and partitions are formed?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Suppose we have a Graph G=(V,E) , we need to remove some edges to make it into two connected components. The constraint here is that, the edges we need to remove , should be of maximum weight.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have described is known as [maximum weighted cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut) and it is known to be NP-Complete. Because it is NP-Complete, you won't find efficient exact algorithms but I imagine there are many heuristics that run quickly. In particular, there are probably fast (in practice) integer and linear programs for computing maximum cut.